# Robolectric StackOverflowError when multiple calls to buildActivity

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric to unit test. Why do i get a stackoverflow exception when i do this?

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    subject1 = buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create();
    subject2 = buildActivity(AnotherActivity.class).create();
}
```

I would like to merely have two different activities because i will switch on and off between the two in different tests.

Comment: I understand this was quite a while ago, is it possible to post a stack trace?